# Okta OktaSignIn Widget Token Refresh

Tags: okta-api, okta-signin-widget

I have a website to use Okta to authenticate/authorize. I am able to use Okta sign in widget to get access token and make API call.

```
let oktaSignIn = new OktaSignIn({
      baseUrl: 'https://dev-xyz.okta.com',
      logo: '../img/hello.png',
      clientId: '0oa11nSOMETEXTudr5d7',  
      redirectUri: 'http://localhost:5000/login/callback', // Not sure if it's needed
  
      authParams: {
          issuer: 'https://dev-xyz.okta.com/oauth2/default',
          responseType: ['id_token', 'token'],
          //scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access', 'email', 'profile'],
          scopes: ['openid', 'offline_access'],
      }
  });

  this.oktaSignIn.renderEl({
      el: '#widget-container'
  }, function success(res) {
      if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') {

        let tokens = res.tokens;

        // Store access token and use it to make API call hosted at http://localhost:5000/myapi
      }
  }
```

The token expires in 60 minutes. I am not sure how to use refresh token with OktaSignIn widget. I could not find any sample.

I looked these links:

https://developer.okta.com/code/javascript/okta_sign-in_widget/#sign-in-and-display-user-s-email
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@okta/okta-signin-widget/v/4.5.0
https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget

But, I could not find no any sample.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to use OktaSignIn to get refresh token?
2. How to use refresh token with OktaSignIn?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the tokenManager, it will handle refreshing the token for you

```
signIn.renderEl({ el: '#widget-container' }, async (res) => {
        if (res.status === 'SUCCESS') {
          signIn.tokenManager.add('id_token', res[0])
          signIn.tokenManager.add('access_token', res[1])
        }
      })
```

Now every time you use

```
signIn.tokenManager.get('access_token')
```

You are guaranteed to have a valid non expired token